# Detect if linked list contains a loop

Tags: java, linked-list, interview-questions

The following is a code to detect a loop in a linked list. This question is prepared strictly for interview purposes. This code has been modeled as per Linkedlist.java

1. How should I decide if a function like `hasLoop()` should be included as an instance method or should be a static method similar to `sort` in Collections.java?
2. Ideally I would inherit `Linkedlist` and add an extra function `mergeSort` to the subclass, but the interviewer would not like it, thus I should keep my solution without inheriting linkedlist for interview sake.  Do you agree?

```
    public class DetectLoopExistance<E> {

    private Node<E> first;
    private Node<E> last;

    public void add(E element) {
        final Node<E> l = last;
        final Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(element, null);
        last = newNode;
        if (first == null) {
            first = newNode;
        } else {
            l.next = newNode;
        }
    }

    private static class Node<E> {
        E element;
        Node<E> next;

        Node(E element, Node<E> next) {
            this.element = element;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }


    public boolean hasLoop() {
        Node<E> fast = first;
        Node<E> slow = first;

        while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
            fast = fast.next.next;
            slow = slow.next;
            if (slow == fast) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
   }
```

Comment: I know this is for an interview, but if I were hiring, I would want you to tell me that you would design the linked list api such that you would never end up with a loop.

Comment: @toto2 And how would you show that your library created good loops?  With a test - one that should become a unit test, bundled with the library source.  If you tried to tell me that the test was not necessary, I would know never to hire you.

Comment: @itsbruce Agreed that it makes sense as a unit test.  It should probably not be a public class method however.  And I still stand by my main point that the public api of that linked list class should never allow a loop to be created.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linked list loop detection in Java(interview question)](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2711/linked-list-loop-detection-in-javainterview-question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, I would create the method as a static method, because similar to sorting, detecting loops is basic functionality, that is applicable to `List`s in general, not only a specific `List` object.

I would not recommend inheriting from the original List implementation in order to create the merge sort functionality. If you do so you will end up with `List` objects that can be sorted using merge sort and `List` objects, that cannot. But there is not really a difference between the two in structure, the only difference is that one is you inherited version and one is the `LinkedList` implementation. This complicates things unnecessarily. Again I would create a static method to merge sort any `List`, which would add the ability to merge sort any `LinkedList`, any `ArrayList` and any other custom `List` implementation, that implements the Java `List` interface.

Comment: where would u add the static function ? Would it be in the 'DetectLoopExistance' class or in another UtilityClass ? If its added in DetectLoopExistance the it would it take List as parameter ? If it does then if i want to sort an instance, I would need to do somthing like DetectLoopExistance.mersort(instance) rather than instance.mergeSort(). If I create a utility function then it how would it do ptr.next, when next belongs to 'private nested class' ?

Comment: i would go for another utility class. `DetectLoopExistance.mergeSort(someList)` wouldn't really make sense although `SortHelper.mergeSort(someList)` would.
For the `ptr.next` thing I guess I would try and find the implementation of the default sort functions and see how it is done there.

Comment: Thanks but how would For the ptr.next be used ? I mean for all linkedlist interview questions we need to use ptr.next ? What would we do it then ?

Answer (score 2):

Your loop detection will almost always take longer than the classic hare and tortoise implementation; in the case where the entire list is one loop, it will take nearly twice as long.  Consider that latter case:

You will not detect the loop until the **slow** node has caught up with the **fast** node, while the classic implementation detects when **fast** catches and passes **slow**.  Your implementation will only return when **slow** has run once through the list and returned to the first node (and **fast** has therefore looped twice through the list).  The classic method will return once **slow** has reached **list.size() - 2** where **list.size()** is even or **list.size() - 1** where it is odd  (this is the point at which it will be lapped).  In a list of 1 or 2 nodes, **slow** never moves at all.

Adapting your version minimally to make it into the classic implementation gives this:

```
public boolean hasLoop() {
  Node<E> fast = first;
  Node<E> slow = first;

  while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
    if (slow == fast.next || slow == fast.next.next) {
      return true;
    } else {
      fast = fast.next.next;
      slow = slow.next;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This can be optimised to remove the duplicated iterations of **fast.next** but I left it like this for greater clarity.